# Is @PostConstruct method called for a static method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, static

I am wondering whether @PostConstruct method is ever called when a static method from a component is called for e.g.

```
@Component
public class SomeComponent{
    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;
    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;
    private static SomeService someService;
    private static CacheManager cacheManager;
    @PostConstruct
    void init(){ 
    SomeComponent.someService = someService;
    SomeComponent.cacheManager= cacheManager;// set up static variables
    };

    SomeComponent{};

    public static List<MyObjectDTO> someStaticMethod (){
    List<MyObjectDTO> returnList = new ArrayList<MyObjectDTO>();
    returnList = getCacheList();
    .
    .
    //does some more manipulation to that list
    return returnList;
   }
   
   private static List<MyObjectDTO> getCacheList() {
   SomeComponent someComponent = new someComponent();
   return someComponent.setAndGetCachedList();
   }

   private List<MyObjectDTO> setAndGetCachedList (){
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    someService.getList(); //sets the cache first
    Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("MyCache");
    Type list = new TypeToken<List<MyObjectDTO>>(){}.getType();
    List<MyObjectDTO> cacheList = modelMapper.map(cache.get(SimpleKey.EMPTY).get(), list)); //maps the cached list to list of MyObjectDTO
    return cacheList;
   };
}
```

```
@Service
public class SomeService{

    public method(){
        SomeComponent.someStaticMethod(); //is @PostConstructor called here?
    }
}
```

Is @PostConstructor method ever called when the static method of the component is called above? If not, in what way can the @PostConstructor method be called? Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `@PostConstruct` can not be applied to a static method.  The whole point of this annotation is to be called on a method of a Bean after the bean has been constructed.  In the case of a static method, there is no corresponding Bean (Java object) and so it doesn't make sense to have a static `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense, thank you! What if I have static variables which I am currently setting in ```@PostConstruct ```method, if I remove ```@PostConstruct``` how can I initialize them with the static method call?

Comment: The point of PostConstruct is again, that code gets called after a Bean has been constructed.  There is a reason to want the code in question to run at that time.  In your case, when do you want the code to run that sets the static variables?  I expect that it has something to do with when data is available.  You can go ahead and put PostConstruct on the method of one of your Beans, and then have that method set the static variables when it runs.  This is a fairly common thing to do if, especially if the Bean in question is required to be able to set the static variable to the right value.

Comment: If your question is still unanswered (or poorly answered ;o) ), I would suggest that you post some code and explain a little more about what it is you're trying to accomplish.  The sample code you provide seems to be just for illustrating the concept.  Show us more about what you're really trying to do.

Comment: I just added more code to show what I am trying to accomplish. So basically "SomeComponent" is a helper class like ObjectUtils which has one public static method. This method is used to fetch a list of cached list. Hope my code is clearer now.